# How to loop through a console program that runs multiple instances and close the instances that runs to long

Tags: powershell

I've a program that runs multiple instances to print labels. somtimes those instances don't stop running and I need to clean up the instances that are running too long.  How can I do it with a powershell script and schedule it each minute

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Nothing for the moment, because I've no experience in powershell.

Comment: Then please find a PowerShell tutorial first, or hire someone who does have PowerShell experience. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Wow, I write a lot of code, just ask some info to start...I will not hire you, that's for sure

Comment: please review - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi i wanted to use this code Get-Process MyProgram |   Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }, but can I add code here to check when a program started to run?

Comment: If you take a look at `Get-Process | Get-Member` you may notice a property `StartTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the solution. Is this code OK?

```
$list = get-process SapLabel | select id, StartTime
foreach ($item in $list)
{
     $t1 = Get-Date
     $t2 = $item.StartTime  
     $TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $t2 $t1
     if($TimeDiff.Seconds -gt 90)
     {
         Stop-Process -Id $item.Id
     } 
     else 
     {
        [string]$item.Id + " is OK: seconds running => " + [string]$TimeDiff.Seconds
     }
     }
```